# Why is Tifa's Strength and Dexterity not reaching 255?

Tags: final-fantasy-7

I'm starting to farm the Sources in *Final Fantasy VII* and I'm having some trouble.

For some reason for every character with the guard, luck and strength sources it allowed me to increase every character stats to 255 but for Tifa it stopped increasing no matter how many additional sources i give to her, 250 in Strength and at 254 in Dexterity

is there a limit for Tifa stats or could someone tell me what is going on?

Comment: Check your equipment. From [this](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/197341-final-fantasy-vii/62139519) guide, you might have materia equipped that are reducing your stats.